# Irregular behavior using the viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I am trying to update some of my views when they appear, so I naturally found myself using the viewDidAppear: and viewWillAppear: methods.  However, I have experienced two problems with using these methods:

1. When I only implement one of the methods, the changes that I am looking to make are not completely there, so in order for everything to work, I implemented both methods with the same code.
2. Even after implementing both methods with the same code, there is a 0.5 to 1 second delay when updating the view's content.

Here is my code for my custom made table view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

For some reason, I must call the reloadData method twice to completely update my table view.

Here is my code for my custom made normal view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    navItem.title = @"Name1";
    nameLabel.text = @"Name1";
    nameField.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    navItem.title = @"Name1";
    nameLabel.text = @"Name1";
    nameField.hidden = YES;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you need to use only one method, it is strange that if you are using one then it's not working for you, is it always a issue for you?

Comment: This is the first time that I am using these methods, so I guess it always has been an issue for me.

Comment: just try using only viewWillAppear once again and put a breakpoint, then check if control is there or not?

Comment: also which method you are using to load the view - viewDidLoad or loadView or any other one?

Comment: have you tried debugging as well? Whether control came there?

Comment: Sounds weird. What does "... changes ... not completely there ..." mean? Is it only that some of the subviews/tableCells change while others keep the old value? I'd try different things now (cause I don't know the answer). 1. Test without impl of viewDidAppear, call super viewWillAppear:animated] at the end of the impl., NSLog to see if viewWillAppear got called. If fail try with viewDidDisappear instead of viewDidAppear, test with that impl alone, NSLog etc. ... just experiment.

Comment: When I say that the changes are not completely there, I mean that only one or two of the changes were made.  For example, on my table view, I need reloadData to add a new cell and set the text on its title label.  However, implementing only one of the methods will add the cell, but replace it with an existing one.  When I implement both methods, table view acts as expected.

Comment: I also tried to implement the other available methods in different ways, but the only methodology is the one that I previously used.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the `viewWillAppear` method.